# Is there a way of getting the process id of my C++ application?

Tags: c++, macos, macos-carbon

Is there a way of getting the process id of my C++ application? I am using the Carbon framework, but not Cocoa…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

can you use the getpid() function found in unistd.h ?

[osx reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/getpid.2.html)

Answer (score 1):

GetProcessPID is what you need. This takes a ProcessSerialNumber, which you can obtain from GetCurrentProcess.

Comment: That's the objective c api, the question is for c++

Answer (score 1):

Note that you don't actually need to call GetCurrentProcess, you can use the constant kCurrentProcess.

(But getpid is a lot less work if you're not trying to access another process's PID, anyway.)