# How do you get the current process ID in Mac kernel extension code?

Tags: macos, kernel, pid, kernel-extension, xnu

I was initially trying to use `getpid()` in my kernel module for OS X/macOS, is there a way to get the PID (process ID) of the process in whose context my kext is running in the kernel? Is there an existing function or variable that I can use ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676/is-there-a-way-of-getting-the-process-id-of-my-c-application. It's available in unistd.h.

Comment: @AndrewHenle why would you think will I post this and dig so much into the libraries if I already did not google it #facepalm

Comment: Because [searching Google for "getpid() on mac"](https://www.google.com/search?q=getpid()+on+mac) returns as its very first result [the Mac `getpid(2)` man page](http://www.manpages.info/macosx/getpid.2.html) which clearly states you need `#include <sys/types.h>` and `#include <unistd.h>`, neither of which are mentioned in your question. #facepalm indeed.

Comment: i got the issue I was trying this in the kernel and i think getpid() does not work for the kernel

Comment: @AndrewHenle do u have any inputs on that ?

Comment: The process ID of what? Kernel extensions aren't processes.

Comment: @duskwuff 
I need to print out the PID of the process using my kext

Comment: Well… what is your kernel extension? What would be "using" it? What context would its code be running in?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The OP is not asking how to get the PID of the process their code is in, because their code is not part of a user process. They are asking how to get the PID of the process that initiated a request that caused their kernel extension to be invoked.

Comment: Seems like a legit question to me. Whoever marked the question to be closed as "too broad": please consider that you might not have understood the question. You really shouldn't flag to close questions just because you don't know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the PID of the process with which the currently running kernel thread is associated, call the [`proc_selfpid()` function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1488971-proc_selfpid?language=objc); you'll need to `#include <sys/proc.h>` in your kext's code to get the prototype. The PID will of course only correspond to a user process if your code is running in the context of some kind of callback for a syscall.